# Finding solutions to the wave equation wich vanish on an interval

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This question is about an exercise in Shubin's invitation to PDE. I want to show that the only solution to the one-dimensional wave equation $u_{tt} = a^2 u_{xx}$, $x\in\mathbb{R},t\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $u(x,t)$ vanishes on a certain interval $(x_1-\epsilon,x_1+\epsilon)$ is $u\equiv 0$.

I tried to tackle the problem by first reducing to the case where $x_1=0$. We know that the general solution is $f(x+at)+g(x-at)$ for some $f,g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$. What I understood so far is that the vanishing condition imposes a certain symmetry on the solution: if we have $(x_0,t_0)$ in the x-t plan, then the line $x_0-at_0=x-at$ must intersect $x=0$ at some point (precisely at $(0,\frac{-x_0}{a}+t_0))$. At that point, the vanishing condition on the solution tells us that $f(-x_0+at_0)=g(x_0-at_0)$. Since $x_0$ and $t_0$ where arbitrary, this should hold at any point and we rewrite $u(x,t)=f(x+at)-f(-x+at)$.

I've been stuck here for a couple of days now. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's way easier than you think! if $u(x_0,t)=0$ for any $t \in (-\infty,+\infty)$, then
$$
f(x_0-at)+g(x_0+at)=0 \quad \forall t\in (-\infty,+\infty). \tag{1}
$$
since $u$ is always zero on this interval and $\epsilon >0$ :
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
u_t(x_0,t)=0 \\
u_x(x_0,t)=0
\end{array}\right.
 \Longrightarrow
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
-f'(x_0-at)+g'(x_0+at)=0 \\
f'(x_0-at)+g'(x_0+at)=0
\end{array}\right.
$$
and since this is for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore $f(\xi)=C_1$ , $g(\eta)=C_2$ for all $\xi ,\eta \in \mathbb{R}$ for some $C_1,C_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.
And finally by equation (1) we deduce that $f(x)=-g(x')=C \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $x,x' \in \mathbb{R}$. 
so for any $(x,t) \in U \times \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
u(x,t) = f(x-at)+g(x+at) = C-C = 0.
$$

Comment: Physical intuition of this solution is also interesting. constant pattern of wave (shape of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$) moving at constant speed ($a$) at one direction ($f(x)$ moving toward positive $x$ and $g(x)$ moving toward negatives). so for any $x$ at any time $t$, there is a time at past or future which pattern of $u(x,.)$ at $(x-\epsilon',x+\epsilon)'$ (for $0<\epsilon' \leq \epsilon$) was or will be inside $(x_0 - \epsilon, x_0 + \epsilon)$ which is zero function. so $u=0$!